# Set a setInterval function as session variable in expressJS?

Tags: node.js, express, variables, session, setinterval

Is it possible to store a setInterval function as session variable in expressjs?, for example:

```
let req.session.timer = setInterval(function() => {
    console.log('timer set');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Why do that when you could just set a session var as a timestamp, then have the app code set a timer based off of that?

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `setInterval` is just a number. You can store numbers in sessions without any problems.